# objective C, properties vs ivars

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables

I suspect that this question has been asked and answered, but I have read many posts on it and I'm not totally clear on the answer.

I generally find it quite convenient to declare private variables as instance variables in the   implementation section of my.m files like so:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    int someNum;
    NSObject *myObj;
}
```

Is this ok, and or best practice currently? Do I need to be declaring properties instead for some reason?

Comment: Declaring variables in .h file and making it as @private is older way of coding. Have those variables in your .m implementation in fact that is the current industry standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One technique is to declare a class extension within the `.m`

```
@interface MyViewController() {

NSInteger someNumber;
NSObject *myObject;

}

@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(void)someMethod {

someNumber++;

}

@end
```

Assuming `ARC` you will get strong references to object types. Thats not any different from what you did. Its just separating interface and implementation more clearly and also lends itself to patterns such as `Private Implementation`

However with properties you get the opportunity to manipulate the accessors and also you get `KVC` for free.

```
@interface MyViewController() {

    NSInteger someNumber;

}

@property (copy,readwrite,nonatomic) NSObject *myObject;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(void)someMethodWhichNeedsACopy:(NSObject *)aobj {

self.myObject = aobj; //free copies , no smudging!

}

@end
```

And in addition allows you to override

```
-(void)setMyObject:(NSObject *)aobj

-(NSObject *)myObject
```

or just access the implicit private ivar

```
[_myObject doSomethingCool]; 

_myObject.thing = something;
```

or use the KVC given to you by the generated accessors

```
[myViewControllerInstance addObserver:someOtherObject forKeyPath:@"myObject" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL]
```

after which `someOtherObject` will receive messages of the form

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

In short. What you are doing is not wrong but there are other techniques and tools to explore with which you can do more stuff.

Comment: Basically use the style which gives you clear maintainable code. If you are in a corporate gig even more so.